# Is it possible to remove actual post pages in wordpress but keep them in categories

Tags: posts, categories

I have little content on my post pages so I would like the actual post pages to be hidden **but** I would like the content of the post to show on the category pages. Will wordpress allow this?

Comment: Sorry, it's not entirely clear what you're asking for. Do you want to have full posts shown on category pages and no singular post view?

Comment: Let me try and be more clear...Would like post pages to be eliminated or hidden on site but would like the content on the post pages to be visible on the category pages.

Answer (score 0):

If you have posts that only should be displayed on category extract-type pages, then set your site to show a static page on the home page, rather than the latest posts.

This setting may be in your theme options, or in the Settings, Reading screen. (Some themes may override the Settings, Reading settings, so check both place.)

**Added 2/28**

If you want to have a page that only shows posts of a certain category, then creating a template for that category might be the answer. One way to do that is discussed here: http://www.wpbeginner.com/wp-themes/how-to-create-category-templates-in-wordpress/ . You can use that as a starting point.

There are also 'category page' plugins, but a template might be best.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, I am not quite sure that would work, my concern is not the homepage, it pretty much is static I disabled posts there. My concern is with the post pages itself. I dont want my posts to show anywhere on my site except the category page it is in. I was thinking maybe a redirect of all post pages to category pages would work?

Comment: See my revised answer (revised 2/28).